# access token usage in authentication

Tags: rest, security, authentication

I don't understand the point of having access token in authentication. Below is a paragraph of explanation I took but I still confused. Since every api call still go to the db look for the token, what's the different check for the username and password for every http request?

> Instead of forcing clients to send username and password with every
>   request you can have a "get_access_token" function in your RESTful
>   service that takes the username and password and responds with a
>   token, which is some sort of cryptographic hash that is unique and has
>   some expiration date associated with it. These tokens are stored in
>   the database with each user. Then the client sends the access token in
>   subsequent requests. The access token will then be validated against
>   the database instead of the username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Using the access token limits the amount of time the username and password are being used and sent across the wire.

How many times do you want your username and password, SSN, or other sensitive data do you want being stored and transmitted? Do you want that on every request?

Comment: Where does the token come from? It's generated on the fly after the auth succeed right? So where should I store the token to make it act like the session?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, access tokens are typically validated by checking the digital signature, which does not require the receiving service to talk to the issuing server. The client gets an access token once and uses it until it expires.

But even if the token had to be checked against the database on every call (when using reference tokens for example), tokens are still preferred over sending username and password on each call. They remove the need for the client to keep the password in memory (or elsewhere), where it can easily be stolen.

Comment: If a hacker got my token, means he can access to my protected api, he can ruin things too.

Comment: @Jennifer yes, if a hacker gets your token, he can do whatever you could do with that token. You can limit the scope of a token. Username/password typically gives full control.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Access token is less sensitive than your password.  Access tokens typically expire after a short time (this is a requirement in the Oauth threat model), whereas passwords tends to be long term.  If somebody grabs your access token, there is limited damage they can do.  If they grab your password, then there is a lot of damage that they can do.  Especially if you use the same or related passwords on multiple sites.

(2) If the server implemented password verification securely, then they should be using a **slow** function like PBKDF2, bcrypt, or scrypt to validate your passwords.  These functions are designed to be slow so that if somebody gets access to the database, they will not be able to reverse many passwords: see [Our password hashing has no clothes](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/06/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes.html).  Given that password checking is supposed to be slow, we don't want to be doing it often!  Validation of access tokens is much quicker however.

(3) The system that grants you access to a resource ("resource provider") might not be the same as the system that checks your identity ("identity provider").  For example, many websites including StackOverflow allow you go login with your gmail account.  In this case, Google is the identity provider and StackOverflow is the resource provider.  Would you really want to provide your gmail password to StackOverflow?  I hope not.

Comment: 1) how do you generate token and make it expired? 2) understood this 3) so authentication is done in stackoverflow and it return u a token to do things in gmai? if I'm right how you keep the token moving around in gmail? I'm using restful api so it would be stateless how should i use the token? store it in localstorage? or use it in memory?

Comment: (1) You set an expiry time in the database and you enforce that in your code.  (3) No, the opposite: authentication is done in gmail, which returns a token valid for Stack Overflow.  You should only worry about (3) if you are allowing authentication to happen from external entities.  Many apps handle authentication only internally.